# Percentage Calculation always returns 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to calculate the percentage of something.
It's simple maths. Here is the code.

```
float percentComplete = 0;
if (todaysCollection>0) {
    percentComplete = ((float)todaysCollection/(float)totalCollectionAvailable)*100;
}
```

Here the value of todaysCollection is 1751 and totalCollectionAvailable is 4000. Both are int.
But percentComplete always shows 0. Why is this happening? Can any one Help me out.
I'm new to Objective C.

Comment: to start with, I think you should test the divisor for zero!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Wouldn't that result in NaN?

Comment: but the divisor already 4000, "totalCollectionAvailable is 4000"

Comment: @thyrgle: it's still a good idea to test the divisor for zero anyway.

Comment: How have you determined the various values?  Can you show a working program - that is, a program that compiles and runs but that produces the erroneous result?  There is no obvious reason why the code should fail - unless the division was somehow done on integers instead of floating point values.  Which can't happen as written...

Comment: @thyrgle: I wasn't suggesting that was the solution, just that it needing doing.

Comment: @BoltClock and Mitch Wheat: Sorry I thought he/you were suggesting a solution...

Answer (score 11):

> But percentComplete always shows 0

How are you displaying percentComplete? Bear in mind it's a float - if you interpret it as an int without casting it you'll get the wrong output. For example, this:

```
int x = 1750;
int y = 4000;
float result = 0;
if ( x > 0 ) {
    result = ((float)x/(float)y)*100;
}
NSLog(@"[SW] %0.1f", result);   // interpret as a float - correct
NSLog(@"[SW] %i", result);      // interpret as an int without casting - WRONG!
NSLog(@"[SW] %i", (int)result); // interpret as an int with casting - correct
```

Outputs this:

```
2010-09-04 09:41:14.966 Test[6619:207] [SW] 43.8
2010-09-04 09:41:14.967 Test[6619:207] [SW] 0
2010-09-04 09:41:14.967 Test[6619:207] [SW] 43
```

Bear in mind that casting a floating point value to an integer type just discards the stuff after the decimal point - so in my example 43.8 renders as 43. To round the floating point value to the nearest integer use one of the rounding functions from math.h, e.g.:

```
#import <math.h>

... rest of code here

NSLog(@"[SW] %i", (int)round(result)); // now prints 44
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try with *(float)100, sometimes that is the problem ;)

Comment: Most probably not, as only one of the operands has to be a float in order for the expression to evaluate as a float (thanks to implicit casting). That is just my intelligent deduction, though.

Comment: Dont know exactly how it looks in obj-c but in C# i had similar problem with that. (float)/(float) can be casted to (int) before *.

Comment: float/float is always type float

Comment: Yes, i know that float/float is float, but float * int (because in this case 100 is int, not float, 100.0 would be float) may result of int * int. Thats why i recomended casting 100 to type.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your value for `todaysCollection` and `totalCollectionAvailable` is wrong. Double check for that.

Put the `NSLog(@"%d", todaysCollection)` right before the if statement